# Name of a book, tiered cake world

Tags: story-identification

I want to know the name of a fantasy book, adventure.
The reading is for children/young people. I read it about 10 years ago, I would say that it is a book written in the 2000s, maybe a little earlier.
The most notable thing about the book is that its world is shaped like a tiered cake. The higher the level of the cake, the better the living conditions.
The protagonist is a boy who works in the worst of levels, in something like a plantation. They used as slingshot weapons.
The plot is how the protagonist tries to reach the top by climbing the walls of the circles. I know that at the end of the book he reaches the top, but there he discovered some secret about his world.
I know that at least it had a sequel, I don't know if it was two books, a trilogy or more.

Comment: Your question has been closed as a Duplicate since it's been answered before. Note that this does not mean this is a bad question — it's quite adequate — but we simply have a bookkeeping method to link questions that are the same to make it easier to find things.

Answer (score 2):

After a little more research, I found the book is *[Atherton: The House of Power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atherton:_The_House_of_Power)* by Patrick Carman.

> Atherton's society is closely knit to its physical geography. Unlike other planets, Atherton is not shaped like a sphere. Rather, it is shaped roughly like an elongated birthday cake, with each layer having less circumference than the one below it. Atherton has three layers: the Flatlands, the bottom and most barren layer

....

> **Edgar** – An orphaned Tabletop-dweller who works in the Grove. He enjoys climbing the hazardous cliffs that form the edge of the Highlands layer. While climbing, he finds a book that plunges him into an adventure about the true nature of Atherton, and the crisis threatening to turn his world inside out.

Comment: It looks like you accidentally created two accounts. You can consult the guide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) to learn how to merge them so that you can accept your answer. Side note, congrats on finding your answer! What worked to find it for you?

Comment: Unaccepted answer to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76443/boy-on-planet-with-three-tiers-tries-to-climb-to-the-top-tier-but-gets-stuck-in/76446#76446, accepted answer at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/260209/book-about-boy-and-animal-going-to-top-of-world-with-interesting-shape/260214#260214

Comment: Ah, and never mind the advice on merging... I misread the scores. As a self-answer, you won't be able to accept by clicking on the checkmark for two days, but we definitely encourage you to do so. :) And stick around... you never know where you might be able to get more answers, or help someone else. I do recommend the [tour] to learn what we're about.